# Why the error 'The following classes could not be instantiated in custom views' is showing in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, I am creating views with extending relative class(For text view i am extending native textview in my java class) because I want to give custom font and don't want to apply font in every individual text view. For this I am using below code

```
public class LoyaltyTextView extends TextView {
    private final static String DROID_SANS = "droid_sans";
    public LoyaltyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }

public LoyaltyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    parseAttributes(context, attrs);
}

public LoyaltyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    parseAttributes(context, attrs);
}

private void parseAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray values = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.LoyaltyTextView);
    String typeface = values.getString(R.styleable.LoyaltyTextView_customTypeFace);
    if(typeface.equalsIgnoreCase(DROID_SANS)) {
        setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "DroidSans.ttf"));
    }

    values.recycle();
}
```

}

and i am using above custom control in xml as mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_splash">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tv_logo"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_m" />

            <customconstrols.LoyaltyTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="@string/loyalty_logo"
                android:textSize="@dimen/logo_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:customTypeFace="DROID_SANS" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <com.customconstrols.LoyaltyTextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login"
                />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but when I use simple text views (as native android widget) it works fine but when i use above custom control preview section starts giving me error as mentioned in picture

[image]

I have tried number of solution which were mentioned in different post like clear cache/invalidate option and refresh layout and cleaning project and rebuilding it but nothing worked for me. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Use tip from the exception - skip setting typeface when view is in edit mode.

Comment: I have already tried that too :( .I have committed the code the is setting type face still having same error. and it is too irritating whenever I do small amount of change this pop up comes up

Comment: try to setcustom font in java class.

Comment: by this way I will have to set font in every text view in every class .Let suppose if a10 activities and every activity has number of textviews than it is long process. Do we have any other short alternate

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code as following line in your xml

xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Run your app,It will work fine.

Comment: It can not initiated in xml in android studio tool. but it will fork fine with app.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyFontTextView extends TextView {

    private Typeface typeface;

    public MyFontTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.app);
        String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.app_customFont);
        setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
        a.recycle();
    }

    private boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        try {
            if (typeface == null) {
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),
                        "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            AndyUtils.generateLog("Exception in component"+e);
            return false;
        }

        setTypeface(typeface);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in **values -> attr.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="app">
        <attr name="customFont" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**Try this**